# D-Link dwr-720 battery indicator

Tags: power

I got a wireless mini-router D-Link dwr-720, the picture used by manufacturer in their datasheets and by e-shops however differs from real look of the product:

[image]

This is how it actually looks:

[image]

As you can see on real product there is no battery indicator, so I am wondering, is there any way to check how much battery is used? This thing doesn't seem to have any manual whatsoever, I can only find technical specifications, but no manual. The web-interface of router shows how much memory is used, but not how much battery is remaining.

Is there any tool or anything that is able to tell you how much battery is remaining?

So far I observer only that when battery is charging the battery indicator is yellow, when it's charged it's green.

When you start up the device it's blue and eventually blinks with purple color - no idea what that means.

Comment: I just bought the same device, but after a complete night charging the led is still yellow. How long does it take for a full charge? Thank you.

Comment: It seems to drain battery faster than it charges so you need to turn it off if you want to charge it fully.

Comment: Hey, after this first night of charging I played a bit with it and plugged it back in... 2h the led went green. So totally it took approximately 10h... thanks

Answer (score 0):

A blue light indicates the battery is over 50%
Yellow for below 50%
Red for below 10%

Amber indicates that its charging

Comment: Double spaces for newlines.